# Can infrared electronics be harmed by an incompatible remote signal?

Tags: infrared

I recently tested a universal remote control app on my phone, for some reason it has a built-in IR blaster.

The initial step is turning on a system by using one its codes. I tried to control my 2010 Sony stereo system with a code closest to my product, but got no response. However, the app contained a sleuth of other Sony codes spanning different models etc (about 400+), and I attempted about a hundred of them to see what might happen.

None of them triggered any responses except one, which turned the stereo on for a split second, then back off. It was an odd behavior, which brings my question: is it safe to use foreign IR codes on electronics that do not necessarily support them, but are still somewhat recognizing them?

I'm sorry if this sounds like a silly question.. i couldn't find any related topics, and I really don't know where else to ask.

Comment: The IR receiver part surely doesn't mind. Switching your stereo on and off quickly might harm it (in the long run) if it wasn't designed for that.

Comment: A really buggy firmware could lock up or produce undefined behavior when it faces an unknown code, but any "damage" would be temporary and repairable by rebooting the device.

Answer (score 5):

It would not damage them. They are designed to ignore spurious signals. While they may sometimes misinterpret bad signals, the worst that would happen is the units thinking they were sent a particular command when they weren't. So it might turn on/off when it wasn't supposed to, it might change channel, turn up/down the volume, etc. It wouldn't do any more harm than if a toddler was randomly pressing buttons on the remote.

There are various kinds of signals an IR remote might send. They are sent on a kind of carrier wave - as with radio signals. And on that carrier wave, bits are sent which represent a command. Usually these are standard commands and carriers, but not always. So this probably explains why your signals are not being interpreted - incompatible carrier, or incompatible commands.

For more information, read [Wikipedia's page on Consumer IR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_IR) which gives an overview of common IR protocols.